# Should we flag abandoned questions for deletion?

Tags: discussion, flags, abandonment

I can't find a clear policy on this.

I consider a question to be abandoned when:

1. It has no answers, and
2. It has at least one comment asking for clarification, suggesting that it *can't* be answered without further details; and
3. The user asking the question hasn't visited the site for *x* months, *or* has not updated the question for *y* months

Is it appropriate to flag a question for moderator attention and just say "Abandoned - delete"?

I've found a bunch of questions satisfying the criteria above but before I flood the mod queue I wanted to make sure I'm not off base.

---

**Update:** I just came across [this description of the current automatic delete process](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78048/enable-automatic-deletion-of-old-unanswered-zero-score-questions-after-a-year).

Looks like we can just rely on that.

Comment: If it has the score of 0 and no answers (for the reason of being unanswerable), then downvoting the question solves the problem: it will be deleted automatically after 30 days.

Comment: Also, if a question is unclear, then *vote to close the post*. Closed posts without answers are also auto-deleted.

Comment: I suppose "vote to close" is a privilege that comes along with more rep than I have accrued on any SE site?  What should us mere mortals do?  Even downvoting hurts when you have two-digit rep.

Comment: @feetwet: You could instead flag-to-close, which will put the question into the close queue for those with close votes to review.

Comment: I've tried a bunch of SE sites and the only flags I can set are "spam," "offensive," or "other (needs moderator attention).

Comment: @feetwet You need 50 points to cast a flag to close. Generally speaking, if your amount of reputation is so low that you can't do that, you should be focusing on contributing to the site by asking and answering. You'll get to moderating tasks later.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier. that does sound like a good generality, but let me offer myself as a counterpoint: I have gone to several sites where I am expert.  I start in the unanswered queue where I provide some answers to old questions.  Apparently those don't attract much attention, so I rarely get a rep from this.  Meanwhile, I'm coming across a lot of questions that haven't been answered because they _can't_ be answered.  And yet I can't flag them appropriately.  Seems like a lost opportunity to organize and improve the site.

Comment: @feetwet I suggest starring ("favoriting") such questions so you can return to them later when you have the points. It's impossible for an expert in the subject of the site to stay below 50 points for long.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If a question isn't answerable due to a lack of information then you should flag/vote to close the question.  (You should do this regardless of whether or not you think the author is active.)  You can also downvote the post to indicate that it is not clear and answerable.

If the post is clarified eventually, it can be reopened.

Questions that have been closed for a while will end up being cleaned up as long as there aren't indications that the questions are of value (i.e. upvotes or upvoted answers).